# How add a new babel plugin in node-modules?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, node-modules, gatsby

I'm trying to install gatsby in my project but I got a babel error:
[image]

What is strange is that I can see the plugin "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx" in my modules ...
I installed it with this command: "npm install --save @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"

Coudl you help me please ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

You need to add `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx` into your `gatsby-config`.

`gatsby-config.js`

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"]
}
```

More documentation can be found here:

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx/.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-config/.